# не могу решить задачу на C

Tags: c

Извините за поздний приход, но нужна помощь. пытаюсь решить задачу и не получается. Кто хорошо знает язык C помогите пожалуйста. Как правильно вынести return, я подзабыл просто.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)  {
    float x, r, a;
    printf("Enter x = ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    for (int i=1; i<=x; i+=5)
    {
        a=(2-x*x)/(sqrt(4*x+5))-1;
        r=log10(a);
        printf("Результат вычислений = %4.2f \n", r);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В принципе всё достаточно тривиально: f(1) у тебя не определена, так как если посчитать повнимательнее, то под логарифмом окажется -2/3. Вполне естественный результат и выходит. Не думаю, что задача в том, чтобы залезть в комплексную арифметику :)

Comment: Я вот тут графичек построил - очень хорошие значения для теста: -0.8, -1.2 и т.д. А вот -1 брать не стоит - там снова функция неограничена

Comment: Не надо так менять вопрос, чтоб он становился другим... Сразу становится непонятно, о чем спрашиваете!

Answer (score 2):

Никуда никакой `return` выносить не надо :)
Достаточно код отформатировать:

```cpp
// Часть программы из вопроса
for (int i=1; i<=x; i+=5)
{
    a=(2-x*x)/(sqrt(4*x+5))-1;
    r=log10(a);
    printf("Результат вычислений = %4.2f \n", r);
}
```

Программа всё правильно считает (не совсем соответствует условию, которое ранее было в вопросе, но это не беда).

Сейчас же достаточно подобрать правильные тестовые числа (1 не подходит). Вот так сама функция выглядит (область определения достаточно явственно видна):

[image: Не определена для 1]

Comment: значит просто подбирать числа а return можно просто убрать из кода?

Comment: @God, никуда ничего убирать не нужно. Тебя запутали

Answer (score 1):

Код надо вставлять текстом.

Вы берете логарифм отрицательного числа. Он не существует. Результат - `nan`  - "Not a Number".

Comment: Там `return` не в цикле - просто беда с форматированием - скобочка там после `printf`

Comment: @God Под вопросом - ссылка "править".